# Can I cancel my B2 visa appointment?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

So I booked for a B2 visa appointment not realising the VWP and no longer need the appointment. Is it ok to cancel my visa appointment and then go for the ESTA instead?

Comment: Yes, but you won't get your money back.

Answer (score 6):

At this stage you haven't actually applied for a visa, you have simply made an appointment. You can cancel your appointment online at any stage, however you will not receive a refund if you have paid any fees.

There's no need to cancel the appointment before applying for an ESTA, so I would suggest applying for the ESTA first, just in case it is rejected for some reason in which case you will still want the visa appointment!

Comment: The second paragraph is particularly deserving of an upvote.